# How to automaticaly upload .json on daily basis to Firebase

Tags: json, firebase, upload, grpc

Our company generates a .json on daily basis containing the data for our mobile app which has the database on Firebase. We upload the data to it manualy, but we've been doing it for couple of months now and it is pain in the butt.

Our suplier tried to create a uploader which works with this cmdlet `gcsupload-windows.exe /key:"C:\Data\myapp-test-sdk.json" /bucket:"myapp-test.appspot.com" /dst:"Import" "C:\Data\json\*.json"` and they created it based on https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/tree/master/storage, but this is not my expertiese, so I can only tell you what it does.

DevOps created a Win Core server for me, they said it is enough, so I am reliant only to CMD...

Once I go to CMD and type the command **outside of the domain** it **does upload** the .json to the server so I am sure that the Uploader and the Command are correct and working properly, BUT when I am in the domain it goes haywire and the cmd replies **Failed to get bucket metadata** and so on..

CMD Input: `PS: D:\Uploader> .\gcsupload-windows.exe /key:"D:\Firebase_Key\myapp-test.json" /bucket:"myapp-test.appspot.com" /dst:"Import-Test" /src:"D:\myapp_json"`

CMD Output: `Failed to get bucket metadata: Get "https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/myapp-test.appspot.com?alt=json&prettyPrint=false&projection=full" oauth2: cannot fetch token: Post "https://oautha.googleapis.com/token" dial tcp 216.58.201.74:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`

Proxy is set correctly on my machine and the trafic is all accepted on proxy server.

The suplier said that it might be something with gRPC, but again, this is not my expertiese, so please, wise stack**overflow**ers ask me, shoot me, just please help me with this. Thank you

Comment: few things you have to do before upload to your could. Be make sure your right access like authentication and authorizations things,
2) Check any firewall restrictions if yes you have to do workaround for that issue

Comment: Auth is ok, firewall is ok, proxy is ok. It has to do something with the uploader I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone still interested in this...
We stumbled across the solution (more like a workaround) by accident. I tried everything I could find on the internet, I had to add this
`$proxyString = "http://proxy:8080" $proxyUri = new-object System.Uri($proxyString) [System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy = new-object System.Net.WebProxy ($proxyUri, $true) [System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials=[System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials`
just to pick up IE settings, which kind of helped, but it was not enough. Some said to modify the Uploader and give it credentials with which I should authenticate against proxy, but this looked unsafe.
I was helpless, tried `invoke-webrequest http://google.com` just to be sure if I am connecting to the proxy, tried the command for the uploader again, and voila - it worked!
It looks like invoke-webrequest is doing something like telling everything behind it to work with the proxy, anyway it works. So my whole script is looking like this:

```
$proxyString = "http://proxy:8080"
$proxyUri = new-object System.Uri($proxyString)
[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy = new-object System.Net.WebProxy ($proxyUri, $true)
[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials=[System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
invoke-webrequest http://google.com
$Env:HTTP_PROXY = "http://proxy:8080"
D:\Uploader\gcsuploader.exe /key:"D:\Firebase_key\myapp-prod-firebase-adminsdk.json" /bucket:"myapp-prod.appspot.com" /dst:"Import" "D:\Myapp_json\*.json" >> "c:\Uploader_logs\uploader $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).log" 2>&1
```